# PHP code doesn't work. No Errors

Tags: php, html, forms

I have this system where I can add new record and edit. Something like a record keeping system. It works smoothly. I've tested it many times to ensure that it's working properly as planned. BUT there will be this instance that it would just not work. And I didn't even touched the codes. I have backup files and it is working. But after overwriting it to the old(assumed to be broken) file it would still not run. No errors, just not functioning well. Here's one

**editprocess-service.php**

```
<?php
  include('check.php'); 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Samson</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/frame2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nav6.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/textbox.css">
<style>
    .myTable { 
        background-color:#eee;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    .myTable th {
        background-color:#407cb9;
        color:white;
        width:;
    }
    .myTable td, .myTable th {
        padding:5px;
        border:1px solid #000;
                }
    .myTable a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: red;
        position: center;
    }
    body{
    background-image: url(images/bg.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-origin: content-box;
  }
</style>
<body style="background-image: url(images/loginbg2.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%;">

<!--Nav-->
<ul>
  <img src="images/logowhite.png" style="margin-left: -728px;">
  <!--style="margin-left: -728px;">-->
  <li style="margin-left: 200px;"><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a class="active">Fill-Up Form</a></li>
  <li><a href="clist.php">Customer List</a></li>
  <li><a href="filem.php">File Maintenance</a></li>
  <li style="float: right"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
    <!--<li style="margin-right: 100px;"><a href="#"> Logout </a></li>-->
</ul>



<div id="container"></div>
<div id="content">
 <br><br>


<?php
    include('connect-db.php');
        if(isset($_GET['CustomerNumber']))
        {
            $CustomerNumber=$_GET['CustomerNumber'];
            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {

                $crc_no = $_POST['crc_no'];
                $date_of_service = $_POST['date_of_service'];
                $date_of_interment = $_POST['date_of_interment'];
                $authorized_family = $_POST['authorized_family'];
                $rel_to_deceased = $_POST['rel_to_deceased'];
                $rel_address = $_POST['rel_address'];
                $service_phone_no = $_POST['service_phone_no'];
                $service_deceased = $_POST['service_deceased'];
                $service_type = $_POST['service_type'];
                $service_amount = $_POST['service_amount'];
                $less_service = $_POST['less_service'];
                $net_amount = $_POST['net_amount'];

                $query3=mysql_query("UPDATE records SET crc_no='$crc_no', date_of_service='$date_of_service', date_of_interment='$date_of_interment', authorized_family='$authorized_family', rel_to_deceased='$rel_to_deceased', rel_address='$rel_address', service_phone_no='$service_phone_no', service_deceased='$service_deceased', rel_address='$rel_address', service_phone_no='$service_phone_no', service_deceased='$service_deceased', service_type='$service_type', service_amount='$service_amount', less_service='$less_service', net_amount='$net_amount' WHERE CustomerNumber='$CustomerNumber'");
                if($query3)
                {
                header('location: fill.php');
                }
                }
                $query1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM records where CustomerNumber='$CustomerNumber'");
                $query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1);
                ?>
            <!--andy -->


<?php
                    include ('connect-db.php');
                    if(isset($_POST['btn_submit'])){
                    $sql = "SELECT records SET
                    CRC = '".$_POST['CRC']."',
                    Name = '".$_POST['Name']."',

                    where CustomerNumber = '".$_POST['CustomerNumber']."'";

                    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
                        header('location:home.php');
                    }else{
                        echo "Error ".mysqli_error($con);
                    }

                }
                $CRC ='';

                if(isset($_GET['CustomerNumber'])){
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM records WHERE CustomerNumber=".$_GET['CustomerNumber'];
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);
                    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                        $CustomerNumber = $row['CustomerNumber'];
                        $CRC = $row['CRC'];
                        $Name = $row['Name'];




                    }
                }   
            ?>  


            <!--endocrine glands-->

                <form method="post" action="">

                <table style="width: 10%;">


 <p style="font-size: 30px; font-family: Verdana;"> &nbsp Service Contract </p>
  <hr style="margin-top: -20px; width: 95%;">

<p style="margin-left: 700px;">CRC No: <?=$CRC?>
 <br></p>

<p style="margin-left: 700px;">Date of Service: <input type="text" name="date_of_service" value="<?php echo $query2['date_of_service']; ?>" />
</p>

<p style="margin-left: 700px;">Date of Internment:  <input type="text" name="date_of_interment" value="<?php echo $query2['date_of_interment']; ?>" />
<br></p>

<p style="margin-left: 50px;">Name of Authorized<br>Family Representative:  <input type="text" name="authorized_family" value="<?php echo $query2['authorized_family']; ?>" />
<br></p>

<p style="margin-left: 50px;">Relation to Deceased: <input type="text" name="rel_to_deceased" value="<?php echo $query2['rel_to_deceased']; ?>" />
<br></p>

<p style="margin-left: 50px;">Address: <input type="text" name="rel_address" value="<?php echo $query2['rel_address']; ?>" />
<br></p>

<p style="margin-left: 50px;">Phone No:  <input type="text" name="service_phone_no" value="<?php echo $query2['service_phone_no']; ?>" />
<br></p>

<p style="margin-left: 50px;">Name of Deceased:  <?=$Name?>
<br><br>




<p style="margin-left: 50px;">
Type of Service:  
<input type="radio" name="service_type" value="Sunny Star">Sunny Star</button>
<input type="radio" name="service_type" value="Lemon Tropic">Lemon Tropic</button>
<input type="radio" name="service_type">White Fairy</button><br> 
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="service_type">Chinese Holy</button>
<input type="radio" name="service_type">Red Ginger</button>
<input type="radio" name="service_type">Blue Days</button>
</p>

 &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 

<!--value="<?php // echo $query2['service_type']; ?>"-->



<p style="margin-left: 50px;">Amount:   <input type="text" name="service_amount" value="<?php echo $query2['service_amount']; ?>" />
  </p>

<p style="margin-left: 410px;">  Less:  <input type="text" name="less_service" value="<?php echo $query2['less_service']; ?>" />
<br></p><br><br>

<p style="margin-left: 410px;">  NET AMOUNT: 
<br></p>

<p style="margin-left: 50px;">LESS: PAYMENTS<br></p>
<table style="border: 1px gray solid; margin-left: 50px;">

<th>Date</th>
<th>O.R.#</th>
<th>Amount</th>
<th>Balance</th>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="less_date_service"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="or_serivce"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="less_amount_service_"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="balance_service"></td><br>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="less_date_service_2"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="or_serivce_2"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="amount_service_2"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="balance_service_2"></td><br>
</tr>
</table><br><br><br>

  <button onclick="myFunction()" name="Submit" style="margin-left: 650px; height: 50px; width: 150px;">Submit</button>

<button type="submit" name="back" onclick="goBack()" style="margin-left: 10px; height: 50px; width: 150px;">Back</button>

<a href="masterlist.php"><button type="reset" value="Reset" style="margin-left: 10px; height: 50px; width: 150px;">Reset</button></a>

<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>

</form>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

THANK YOU!

Comment: Are there possible reasons that may affect the system that cause it to act abnormally? @Weltschmerz

Comment: Yes, buggy code.

Comment: code seems to work for me. Make sure that permission on file are correct (web server can access and run your code). Also replace `include` with `require_once`.

Comment: If it doesn't work maybe there are no errors because they are suppressed. Put `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` on top of the script and the errors (if any) will be displayed on screen.